# How to save top scores of an android game?

Tags: android, storage

I am creating a simple android game. I need to save top 10 scores among all users of the app. For saving top scores of single user, I can use shared Preferences to save data. How can I save top scores among all people playing the game and the list should be available to all users?

Thanks!!

Comment: Use SQLite Database, or gson to serialize object

Comment: You will need online database. Store all score there. Sort top ten and display in user's app,

Comment: Why you like save that?..  Use the webservice every time that you need get that information. It is just show a leader board.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions, including [Google Leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards), which is meant exactly for that, or more general services like [Parse](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide), which allow you to implement it easily (if you don't want to create your own server for handling this)